# Calculator int choice = Integer.parseInt(char_a); java

Tags: java, calculator

Trying to create a simple calculator on java. No errors show up in the code. But it still doesn't work at all. am I missing anything?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class JavaApplication15 {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);



      System.out.println("This is a calculator. Enter a letter followed by a number to calculate it.");
       System.out.println(" S = sine \n C = Cosine \n T = Tangent \n R = Square Root \n N = natural Log \n X = exit the program");
        String num = in.nextLine();

        String sValue = num.substring(2);
        String char_a = num.substring(0);

       int choice = Integer.parseInt(char_a);
       double dValue = Double.parseDouble(sValue);

       while (choice != 'x'){
        switch(choice){

            case 's':
                Math.sin(dValue);
                System.out.println("The sine of your number is " + dValue);
                break;
            case'c':    
                 Math.cos(dValue);
                 System.out.println("The Cosine of your number is " + dValue);
                  break;
            case't':   
                 Math.tan(dValue);
                 System.out.println("The Tangent of your number is " + dValue);
                  break;
            case'r': 
                 Math.sqrt(dValue);
                 System.out.println("The square root of your number is " + dValue);
                  break;
            case'n':    
                 Math.log(dValue);
                 System.out.println("The Log of your number is " + dValue);
                  break;
            case'x':
                break;

        }
       }

    }

}
```

Comment: Please expand on "doesn't work" as that doesn't tell us much that can help us to understand your problem.

Comment: There are likely to be a number of errors.  But this is an obvious one: in the statement `Math.sin(dValue);` you calculate the sine of the value and then throw the result away.  You have to assign the result to something if you want to use it.

Answer (score 1):

I think I see your error.

You're performing operations using the Math class but aren't assigning the result of the operation back to your variable.

For example, `Math.cos(dValue);` should probably be `dValue = Math.cos(dValue);`

Answer (score 0):

There are a few problems with your code.

Firstly, you are not using .substring method correctly. It returns everything from the index you specify to the end of your String. So for a user input of "S 4"

sValue equals to "4", but char_a equals to "S 4".

The way you use substring method is:

```
value = input.substring(2);
operation = input.substring(0,1);
```

I would actually suggest that you use something like:

```
params = input.split(" ");
```

Then you have:

```
params[0] // as your command
```

and

```
params[1] // as your value
```

This way you don't have to worry about how many symbols each bit actually takes up.

Next, don't convert your command to char like this. My previous suggestion means you should really be using something like

```
if (params[0].equals("sin")) {

} else if (params[0].equals("cos")) {

} else {
// catch unknown command
}
```

However, you can convert to char simply by:

```
sValue.toCharArray()[0]
```

Also, there is no reason why your switch statement should be in a while loop. There is nothing to be done continuously, it will just keep printing the same answers. And lastly, ajb said, you calculate the values and throw them away, whilst printing the old value. You have to use:

```
System.out.println("The Tangent of your number is " + Math.tan(dValue));
```

Comment: My main suggestion to you is to use the debugger when your code does not work as you expect because it would help you figure out your problems one by one as you trace your execution.

Comment: I should probably add why you are not supposed to use `Integer.parseInt()`. It will throw a `NumberFormatException` meaning that the string you provided is not actually a number. It is intended for strings like "2.0" not "a". Secondly, another problem with your `substring` use is that you do no checking whatsoever, which is very bad. `split()` will let you inspect the size of your array and make decisions based on that (did the user provide enough arguments?). Otherwise you will also get a `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`, which you do not want :)